# Erro ao salvar entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework, code-first

Estou com um problema muito básico, mas devo estar com falta de café pra entender o que está acontecendo.

Tenho uma entidade assim:

```
public class Client : BaseEntity<Client>
{
    [Required]
    public string CorporateName { get; set; }


    // Várias outras propriedades que eu tirei pra não ficar muita coisa


    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public Client()
    {
        this.User = new User();
    }
}
```

Até ai, não vejo nenhum problema aparente. Porém, minha BaseEntity faz o Create dessa maneira (criei os métodos genéricos pra que todas as minhas entidades funcionem da mesma maneira e eu não tenha que replicar o mesmo código várias vezes):

```
public static void Add(params T[] items)
    {
        using (var context = new DBContext())
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (T item in items)
                    context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                            ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Quando eu tento adicionar um Client, o Add lança um erro dizendo que a propriedade User tem o campo Name que é obrigatório. Porém, eu estou setando o UserID e não o User (por um motivo bem nobre: setando o User e fazendo o Add, ele duplicava o registro do User).

Como eu faço pra que o EntityFramework não tente adicionar pela minha propriedade virtual e adicione apenas pela FK?

Answer (score 1):

> Quando eu tento adicionar um Client, o Add lança um erro dizendo que a propriedade User tem o campo Name que é obrigatório. Porém, eu estou setando o UserID e não o User (por um motivo bem nobre: setando o User e fazendo o Add, ele duplicava o registro do User).

Sim, possivelmente você não está usando o contexto para observar o `User` antes.

> Como eu faço pra que o Entity Framework não tente adicionar pela minha propriedade virtual e adicione apenas pela FK?

Isso não existe, "adicionar pela minha propriedade virtual". Se o Entity Framework compreende que seus objetos ainda não existem, irá inserir como se fossem novos.

Sua função `Add` pode ser considerada um anti-padrão. Não há verificação das entidades associadas antes da adição. O certo seria algo assim:

```
var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserID == 1);
var client = new Client { User = user };
db.Clients.Add(client);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Selecionando um user fará o contexto observar o registro.

Agora, se nenhum dos dois existe, o caminho é:

```
var user = new User { Name = "Fulano" };
var client = new Client { User = user };
db.Clients.Add(client);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Mas dessa maneira, eu teria que criar o CRUD pra cada entidade, correto? Fiz dessa outra maneira pra facilitar e reutilizar o código. É possível, de alguma maneira, deixar o CRUD "genérico" pra todas as minhas entidades sem ter problemas com essas relações?

Comment: Defina "deixar o CRUD genérico". Você tem um cliente que quer relacionar com o usuário. O relacionamento entre `Cliente` e `User` é feito em *Controller*. O código vai ser reutilizado onde?

Comment: Uma mesma BaseEntity pra todas as entidades já com o CRUD implementado. A relação entre Client e User, sim, é feita na Controller, porém, pra eu não ter que ficar implementando o Create na Client, User e em todas as outras entidades, eu criei (baseado em links que achei na internet) essa BaseEntity que faz isso pra todas. Porém, não está funcionando.

Comment: De fato não vai funcionar. Não dá pra fazer isso que você quer apenas com este código. Para cada chave estrangeira, você precisa anexar uma entidade ao contexto e só depois inserir o novo registro.